# what's best way to store photo/video

Tags: database, image, video

I am developing app which will let user to upload his/her photos/videos.

I thought of some ways to do it.

1) Store image in mysql (I am not sure about videos)

2) store images and videos in separate folder and give path of that image/video in database table against owner of image/video.

3) Create separate directories for all the users and store directly into directory and assign that path to database against owner of the image/video.

which of these is best to use for mobile app ?

Any Help would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to store your multimedia files into any object storage service(Amazon S3 for example) and store their relative path along with the file name in the database